# What's causing this extra space below my h2?

Tags: css

I'm trying to get the gold title box flush with the box below it.  With margins set to 0, why aren't they butting up against one another?

http://www.craftonhills.edu/Testing/chctest/Tweets.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**update**:

the `ul.tweet_list` has a default margin. Set it to `margin: 0` and it should work.

---

<strike>Through [margin-collapsing](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/collapsingmargins), the `ul` inside the container creates the margin.</strike>

*(on a first glance I thought the `.widget` was creating the border...)*

Answer (score 0):

The margin on `.tweet-lists` is pushing it away.  My suggestion would be to place the border on the containing div and this will get rid of the collapsing margin.

Answer (score 0):

.tweet_list has a top and bottom margin of 14

Answer (score 0):

The  tag inside the div (with id "tweetlist") has a margin-top of 14 pixels (according to Google Chrome inspector). Setting this to 0 in the css fixes it.

Answer (score 0):

It is your UL element that has a default margin on it.  Set the UL to `margin-top: 0px;` and you should be good to go.